# When login URL changes for few step, How can I get authenticated session in scrapy?

Tags: python, session, scrapy

Login process is …

1. URL A (first login page)
2. URL B (login check page1)
3. URL C (login check page2)
4. URL D (Result page (main page) that I want scrap)

I want to scrape some list in `'URL D'`, but my spider cannot progress in `'URL B'`

How can I pass the login check and get an authenticated session?

**Code**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

class gradeSpider(InitSpider):
name = "grade"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
login_page = "https://www.example.com/login/myweb.jsp?RSP=www.example.com&RelayState=index_SSO.jsp"
start_urls = "https://www.example.com/main/dataList"

def init_request(self):
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)


def login(self, response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'userID':'myid', 'userPW':'mypw'}, callback=self.check_login_response)

def check_login_response(self, response):

    print "+"*50
    print "current URL: " + response.url
    print "+"*50

    #check login success
    if success
        return self.initialized();
    else
        return self.error();

def initialized(self):
    return Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    #doing parse
    print "Success login ready to parse."
```

---

**Log**

```
    2016-09-20 08:59:22 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened

    2016-09-20 08:59:22 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

    2016-09-20 08:59:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023

    2016-09-20 08:59:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) GET https://www.example.com/robots.txt (referer: None)

    2016-09-20 08:59:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200)  GET https://www.example.com/login/myweb.jsp? RSP=www.example.com&RelayState=index_SSO.jsp (referer: None)

    2016-09-20 08:59:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200)  POST https://www.example.com/login/loginCheck.jsp (referer: https://www.example.com/login/myweb.jsp? RSP=www.example.com&RelayState=index_SSO.jsp)

    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    current URL: https://www.example.com/login/loginCheck.jsp 
    // I want currunt URL be start_url ... 
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    2016-09-20 08:59:23 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```